# Azure Functions and IHealthCheck

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

I need to implement the Health Check for Azure Functions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.0

But, in my case instead of using NETCORE 3.0 we need to implement it in NETCORE 2.2

Our main problem is the startup class which inherits from the **FunctionsStartup** which it is quite different from MVC API startup. Thus, the following code could not be implemented in the Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {            
            //Readiness check
            var port = int.Parse(Configuration["HealthManagementPort"]);
            app.UseHealthChecks("/ready", port, new HealthCheckOptions()
            {
                Predicate = (check) => check.Tags.Contains("ready"),
            });
            app.UseHealthChecks("/live", port, new HealthCheckOptions()
            {
                //Exclude all checks and return 200-OK
                Predicate = (_) => false,
            });

        }
```

Have any anyone faced something similar? How can I implement similar behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to monitor your Function whay not try  Application Insights?

Comment: But azure functions are running when triggered so what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 10):

```
app.UseHealthChecks("/ready", port, new HealthCheckOptions()
          {
                Predicate = (check) => check.Tags.Contains("ready"),
          });
```

UseHealthChecks is an extension method that registers [HealthCheckMiddleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Middleware/HealthChecks/src/HealthCheckMiddleware.cs) which invoke a method called CheckHealthAsync in  [HealthCheckService](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/HealthCheckService.cs) class

In order to acheive that in Azure functions you need to do the following:

1. Add Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthCheck nuget package.
2. On your Startup.cs class register your health checks

```
   services.AddHealthChecks()
                .AddCheck<SampleHealthCheck>("Sample")
                .AddCheck<Sample2HealthCheck>("Sample2");
```

3. Create Http trigger function and inject HealthCheckService class

```
public class GetReady
    {
        private readonly HealthCheckService _healthCheckService;

        public GetReady(HealthCheckService healthCheckService)
        {
            _healthCheckService = healthCheckService;
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(GetReady))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "ready")]
            HttpRequest req,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var result = await _healthCheckService.CheckHealthAsync((check) => check.Tags.Contains("ready"), cancellationToken);
            return new OkObjectResult(result);
        }
    }
```

And your endpoint should work same as aspnet core.

Comment: I get this error when doing this: A host error has occurred during startup operation 'debf69cd-3112-4da2-9fe1-4e66fa07dcd9'.
func: Invalid host services. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: The following service registrations did not match the expected services:
  [Invalid] ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService, Lifetime: Singleton, ImplementationType: Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckPublisherHostedService.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

Comment: FYI: this works for me https://github.com/keithsmith21/AzureFunctionHealth Azure Function 3 up

Comment: @tank104 I was experiencing similar issue, and the solution was to use version 3.1.10 of Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks .But I read that some users need to downgrade all their Microsoft.Extensions.xxx packages to v 3.1.10

Answer (score 2):

You can use Health Monitor Feature of Azure function if you are using Consumption based plan.

The Host Health Monitor feature of the Functions Runtime monitors various VM sandbox imposed performance counters. The goal is to temporarily stop the host from doing more work when thresholds for any of the counters are about to be exceeded. This allows the host to avoid hitting hard sandbox limits which could cause a hard shutdown, and also allows the host to gracefully complete in-progress work while waiting for the counters to return to normal limits.

You can read more here in detail:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Host-Health-Monitor

Alternatively you can use application insight for doing health check.You can check these blogs for detailed instruction:

https://zimmergren.net/azure-functions-scheduled-trigger-not-firing-application-insights-monitoring/

[How can you create an API Health check in azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720824/how-can-you-create-an-api-health-check-in-azure)

Hope it helps.