# Health Check Endpoint

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, queue, eventhub

I need to create an azure function (HTTP Trigger) to perform healthcheck. It should return status code 200 if everything is ok and 500 if a problem occurred.

```
[FunctionName("Name")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "health")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        //Check eventhub and queue healthcheck if ok
           //return status code 200
        // If not ok
          // return internal server error
    }
```

This function should check eventhub and queue. I am not sure how to create this endpoint and I found several resource I am not able to figure it out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Functions and IHealthCheck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58574027/azure-functions-and-ihealthcheck)

Comment: Nope I can't get an answer from it for my question

Comment: What sort of health check are you wanting to perform? Your question is very open ended.

Comment: I need to make sure that the services are up and running.

Comment: Have you tried doing,  
 `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
        });
`

Comment: Nope. Is there a more clear implementation for this ?

Comment: Just create a try-catch block and return Ok(); if successfull. And in the catch block you return a 500. Simple